# How can I open a new empty tmux pane when I am working in Vim?

Tags: terminal, vim, tmux

Let's say I am working on an .html (or any text-based) file in vim. Next, I need to open a new pane in the same window to work on the terminal.  How can I achieve that?

I know how to use tmux to open a new pane and then go into vim.  But how do I do the reverse? To open a new tmux pane to work on terminal if i am already in vim window?

**Edit**

I would like to open a new pane instead of tab. Panes will allow me to easily see all the terminals and vim files. I can do `:split` but that would just open a new vim pane instead of a new terminal pane.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you interested in tabs? `:tabnew` will open one more tab

Comment: Hi @SibiCoder, I have edited my question above and it also addresses your suggestion.  Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: I guess you can't open terminal pane from vim. For that case, you have to open another terminal

Answer (score 2):

Try prefix-key followed by shift+double quote. This works for me and I use it frequently. It should open a terminal pane below the vim pane.

```
Cntrl-b
Shift-"
```

Or to have the new terminal pane open beside the vim pane:

```
Cntrl-b
Shift-%
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're forgetting to press the *prefix-key* (`Ctrl+b` by default) before the colon. The right combination is `Ctrl+b` and then `:split-window`.

If you forget to press `Ctrl+b`, the colon will be interpreted by Vim instead of Tmux.

Comment: Hi, thanks @Joan Manuel Rivera, I have tried it and it could only work if you follow the following sequence: Open new terminal > tmux > vim > ctrl+b :split-window, then I was able to open a new terminal. But, if you try the following sequence: Open new terminal > vim > ctrl+b :split-window, it will just open a new vim window, which is not what I try to achieve. Any suggestions?